# Issue with GWT when submitting an action

Tags: java, gwt

When I submit a query to the server, i get:

```
An error occurred while attempting to contact the server. Please check your network connection and try again.
```

I looked on Google and it seems to be an issue with new projects, but mine is not... However, some dependencies have changed.

I switched to GWT 2.7.0 to see. I run Java 7 with Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Server is not running, or was previously set up to listen on a custom port and is now listening on its default port.

Comment: I use the standard eclipse plugin, I did not change any parameter. The basic example works.